# SASS Inheritance with Overrides

Tags: css, sass

SASS inheritance with @extend is really useful.  Something like this is very easy:

```css
.my-base-class {
    font-size: 14px;    
}

.my-extended-class {
    @extend .my-base-class;
    
    color: red;
}
```

What I would like to be able to do, however, is to redefine rules in .my-extended-class that are defined in .my-base-class.  Something like this:

```css
.my-base-class {
    font-size: 14px;
}

.my-extended-class {
    @extend .my-base-class;
    
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

In this instance, the font-size is redefined to be 18px in .my-extended-class.

I do realize that I could just add !important to the font-size in .my-extended-class.  However, I don't want to do this for two main reasons.  #1 I've been taught to avoid !important whenever possible.  #2 I actually want to override fairly complex nested properties.  Something like this:

```css
.my-base-class {
    font-size: 14px;
    
    .child-of-my-base-class {
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 5px;
        background-color: green;
    }
}

.my-extended-class {
    @extend .my-base-class;
    font-size: 18px;
    
    .child-of-my-base-class {
        background-color: purple;    
    }
}
```

Is something like this possible?

Thanks.

Aaron

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem, what you showed as an example will work. It would be the same as if you just listed font-size in the same class twice, the first one would be ignored.See this jsfiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/z15q0s2d/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @BlueCaret for the jsfiddle.

It looks like SASS does indeed do this out of the box; it's just my web compiler in Visual Studio that is broken.

So, question answered.  Thanks.

Aaron